# how to terminate AlertDialog.Builder having ListView once the item is clicked and new alert dialogue is created

Tags: android

I am facing a very strange problem. when I try to launch and alert dialogue when an item is clicked from the ListView. The ListView is still there in the background and launched alert dialogue comes over the ListView. once i click ok/cancel the ListView comes agin in the foreground.
I would like that once the OK/Cancel is clicked from the alert dialogue, both L istView and alertdailogue gets disaappeared.

```
builder.setView(listview);
 listview.SetOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener{

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id){

showsomedialogue();}

 });
```

thanks any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to finish() your ListView containing ctivity, either on click of list-item or on click of cancel button of AlertDialoug

Comment: onfirst dialog click are u want open other dialog than use that showsenderpasswrd(); other wise no need to use that first reply to this i will accept editiing text after  ur response

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the following:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
    // Do anything
    this.finish();
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

According to ur requirement ue alert dialog should be like this

```
   AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(DealsActivity.this);
            adb.setTitle("Are You Sure Want To Delete?");
            adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //add code for  what u want on OK click event 
                    showsenderpasswrd();//this will create another dialogue and make                                                    //this in background.
                    YourActivity.this.finish();

                }});
            adb.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           //add code for  what u want on Cancel click event 
                         YourActivity.this.finish();
                    }});
            adb.show();
```